# How to write the correct unit test in this case

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

I am writing test case for my react component and am using '.toContain' to check but i add onClikc function into it and i wrapped all the html in one quotes it add's a back slash to it .

Code

```
it("renders the correct Props ", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<NotificationItem type="default" value="test"/>)
    expect(wrapper.props()).toContain('{"children": "test", "data-priority": "default", "onClick": [Function onClick]}')
})
```

Error

```

```
expect(received).toContain(expected) // indexOf

Expected value:  "{\"children\": \"test\", \"data-priority\": \"default\", \"onClick\": [Function onClick]}"
Received object: {"children": "test", "data-priority": "default", "onClick": [Function onClick]}

  13 | it("renders the correct Props ", () => {
  14 |     const wrapper = shallow(<NotificationItem type="default" value="test"/>)
> 15 |     expect(wrapper.props()).toContain('{/"children": "test", "data-priority": "default", "onClick": [Function onClick]}')
     |                             ^
  16 | })
  17 |
  18 | it("renders the correct html", () => {

  at Object.<anonymous> (src/Notifications/NotificationItem.test.js:15:29)
```

Comment: What's wrong? What are you asking? (Sorry, but I can't really understand your question.)

Comment: That's intentional. It's escaping the quotes.